# How to update values in a dplyr pipe?

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to update values in a new column.

Here's my data :

```
people<- c("father", "parents", "father", "children", "girl", "boy", "grand father", "grand mother", "grandparents" ) 
dataset0 <- data.frame(people)
dataset0
```

And the output :

```
father              
parents             
father              
children                
girl                
boy             
grand father                
grand mother                
grandparents
```

Expected output :

```
 people           people_update

father            parents   
parents           parents   
father            parents   
children          children
girl              children
boy               children
grand father      grandparents          
grand mother      grandparents      
grandparents      grandparents
```

I tried to use `replace()`

```
dataset <- dataset0 %>%
   mutate(people_update = replace(people, people =="girl", "children")) %>%
   mutate(people_update = replace(people, people =="boy", "children")) 
 dataset
```

but this doesn't work.  The second `mutate()` command cancels the first `mutate()` command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be taken care of with a nested `ifelse` statement, i.e,

```
library(dplyr)

dataset0 %>% 
  mutate(v1 = ifelse(people %in% c('father', 'mother', 'parents'), 'parents', 
             ifelse(people %in% c('girl', 'boy', 'children'), 'children', 'grandparents')))

#        people           v1
#1       father      parents
#2      parents      parents
#3       father      parents
#4     children     children
#5         girl     children
#6          boy     children
#7 grand father grandparents
#8 grand mother grandparents
#9 grandparents grandparents
```

Answer (score 12):

Try `case_when` to specify multiple replacements. It is more concise than multiple `ifelse` statement.

```
library(dplyr)

dataset <- dataset0 %>%
  mutate(people_update = case_when(
    people %in% c("father", "parents")                            ~ "parents",
    people %in% c("children", "girl", "boy")                      ~ "children",
    people %in% c("grandparents", "grand father", "grand mother") ~ "grandparents",
    TRUE                                                          ~ NA_character_
  ))
```

Comment: 0.5 version. I have only people column.

Comment: Mine is `0.7.1`. This `case_when` feature is something new. Please update to the latest version.

Comment: If it still cannot work, use multiple `ifelse` statement or join approach others suggested.

Answer (score 7):

An alternative to `case_when()` or nested `if_else()` is to join with a translation table `map`:

```
library(dplyr)
dataset0 %>% left_join(map)
```

> ```
> Joining, by = "people"
>         people people_update
> 1       father       parents
> 2      parents       parents
> 3       father       parents
> 4     children      children
> 5         girl      children
> 6          boy      children
> 7 grand father  grandparents
> 8 grand mother  grandparents
> 9 grandparents  grandparents
> Warning message:
> Column `people` joining factor and character vector, coercing into character vector
> ```

where `map` is given by

```
map <- tribble(
  ~people, ~people_update,
  "father",            "parents",   
  "parents",           "parents",   
  "children",          "children",
  "girl",              "children",
  "boy",               "children",
  "grand father",      "grandparents",          
  "grand mother",      "grandparents",      
  "grandparents",      "grandparents"
)
map
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 8 x 2
>         people people_update
>          <chr>         <chr>
> 1       father       parents
> 2      parents       parents
> 3     children      children
> 4         girl      children
> 5          boy      children
> 6 grand father  grandparents
> 7 grand mother  grandparents
> 8 grandparents  grandparents
> ```

---

If there are only few, selected items which need to be translated, the code can be modified:

```
# define only items to be changed
map2 <- tribble(
  ~people, ~people_update,
  "father",            "parents",   
  "mother",            "parents",   
  "girl",              "children",
  "boy",               "children",
  "grand father",      "grandparents",          
  "grand mother",      "grandparents"      
)
```

Note that `"mother"` has been added to the translation table.

```
dataset0 %>% 
  left_join(map2) %>% 
  # copy unchanged items
  mutate(people_update = if_else(is.na(people_update), people, people_update))
```

> ```
>         people people_update
> 1       father       parents
> 2      parents       parents
> 3       father       parents
> 4     children      children
> 5         girl      children
> 6          boy      children
> 7 grand father  grandparents
> 8 grand mother  grandparents
> 9 grandparents  grandparents
> ```

Answer (score 3):

The point is at your second `mutate`, where you kept using `people` instead of `people_update` at the x argument.

```
dataset <- dataset0 %>%
               mutate(people_update = replace(people, people == "girl", "children")) %>%
               mutate(people_update = replace(people_update, people == "boy", "children")) 
dataset
```