# Using a function and mutate to create a new column in R

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I've got a school project and I've just spent over three hours trying to figure this out.  My data set's ("df") first variable is "AREA."  I've successfully filtered it down so that the only values are the names of US states.

I'm looking to create a new column/variable that's called "Region."  It takes the state listed in "AREA" and returns one of the four US census region designations.  Apparently there's an existing function already in R (state.region?) but I can't get it to work and I'd rather code it the long way.

This is what I have after cleaning up the data and installing "dplyr," "tidyr," and "stringr," libraries:

```
#Create U.S. Census regions
regionconvert<-function(x)
{
  if(x %in% c("Texas","Oklahoma","Arkansas","Louisiana","Mississippi","Alabama","Georgia","Florida","Tennessee","Kentucky","West Virginia","Virginia","North Carolina","South Carolina", "Maryland","Delaware"))
    {return("South")}
  if(x %in% c("Maine","New Hampshire","Vermont","Massachusetts","Connecticut","Rhode Island","New York","New Jersey","Pennsylvannia"))
    {return("Northeast")}
  if(x %in% c("Ohio","Michigan","Illinois","Indiana","Wisconsin","Minnesota","Iowa","Missouri","North Dakota","South Dakota","Nebraska","Kansas"))
    {return("Midwest")}
  if(x %in% c("Alaska","Hawaii","Washington","Oregon","California","Nevada","Idaho","Utah","Arizona","New Mexico","Colorado","Wyoming","Montana"))
    {return("West")}
}
dfRegion=mutate(df,"Region"=regionconvert(df$AREA))
```

I'm getting the following error and my new data set has "South" for every row:

Warning message:
In if (x %in% c("Texas", "Oklahoma", "Arkansas", "Louisiana", "Mississippi",  :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Any help you can give me to fix this would be much appreciated

Comment: `case_when` is more suitable for this kind of task. Please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44805591/7669809

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Up front, do not use `df$` *inside* your call to `mutate`. One of the appeals (and points) of most of the `dplyr` verb-functions is that they work without needing to be told the dataset object all of the time. So your call should have been something like the following (though it still needs work):

```
mutate(df, Region = regionconvert(AREA))
```

But it goes further: if/when you ever use grouping within a pipe, the variables by themselves (as I showed here) are the effective data for the current group, not the whole data set. If for example we wanted to rank cars' `mpg`, but within each cylinder group:

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% mutate(rnk = rank(mpg))
# # A tibble: 32 x 12
# # Groups:   cyl [3]
#      mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb   rnk
#    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#  1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4   5.5
#  2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4   5.5
#  3  22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1   3.5
#  4  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1   7  
#  5  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2  13  
#  6  18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1   2  
#  7  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4   4  
#  8  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2   5  
#  9  22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2   3.5
# 10  19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4   3  
# # ... with 22 more rows
```

then `rank` is called three times: first time with 11 values (`cyl == 4`), second time with 7 values (`cyl == 6`), third time with 14 values (`cyl == 8`). If instead we had tried to call:

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% mutate(rnk = rank(mtcars$mpg))
```

then the calls to `rank` would have 32 values in each call. (This would have failed, because `mutate` needs each function call to return either 1 value or the same number of values as the input.)

But if you are doing something like

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarize(avg = mean(mpg))
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarize(avg = mean(mtcars$mpg))
```

then the first will give per-`cyl` averages, and the second will report the same global average for all three.

---

Okay, now to your question:

One problem is that your function is expecting `x` to be a singular value (scalar, technically in R it is a vector of length 1). Unfortunately, when called by `mutate` it is passed a vector of values. There are a few ways to handle this, from least-preferred to most:

1. The quickest way to vectorize it is to return the specific region for each value with `ifelse`. I suggest the use of `dplyr::if_else` here, though, since it ensures some type-guarantees (that `base::ifelse` does not).

   ```
   regionconvert2 <- function(x) {
     if_else(x %in% c("Texas","Oklahoma","Arkansas","Louisiana","Mississippi","Alabama","Georgia","Florida","Tennessee","Kentucky","West Virginia","Virginia","North Carolina","South Carolina", "Maryland","Delaware"),
             "South",
             if_else(x %in% c("Maine","New Hampshire","Vermont","Massachusetts","Connecticut","Rhode Island","New York","New Jersey","Pennsylvannia"),
                     "Northeast",
                     if_else(x %in% c("Ohio","Michigan","Illinois","Indiana","Wisconsin","Minnesota","Iowa","Missouri","North Dakota","South Dakota","Nebraska","Kansas"),
                             "Midwest",
                             if_else(x %in% c("Alaska","Hawaii","Washington","Oregon","California","Nevada","Idaho","Utah","Arizona","New Mexico","Colorado","Wyoming","Montana"),
                                     "West",
                                     NA_character_))))
   }
   ```
2. Pre-populate a completely-`NA` output, then replace individual values as we determine them:

   ```
   regionconvert3 <- function(x) {
     out <- x[NA]
     ind <- x %in% c("Texas","Oklahoma","Arkansas","Louisiana","Mississippi","Alabama","Georgia","Florida","Tennessee","Kentucky","West Virginia","Virginia","North Carolina","South Carolina", "Maryland","Delaware")
     out[ind] <- "South"
     ind <- x %in% c("Maine","New Hampshire","Vermont","Massachusetts","Connecticut","Rhode Island","New York","New Jersey","Pennsylvannia")
     out[ind] <- "Northeast"
     ind <- x %in% c("Ohio","Michigan","Illinois","Indiana","Wisconsin","Minnesota","Iowa","Missouri","North Dakota","South Dakota","Nebraska","Kansas")
     out[ind] <- "Midwest"
     ind <- x %in% c("Alaska","Hawaii","Washington","Oregon","California","Nevada","Idaho","Utah","Arizona","New Mexico","Colorado","Wyoming","Montana")
     out[ind] <- "West"
     return(out)
   }
   ```

   I don't like this very much, frankly, since it's hard-coding quite a bit (and has repetitive code), so an improved version is something like:

   ```
   regionlist <- list(
     South = c("Texas","Oklahoma","Arkansas","Louisiana","Mississippi","Alabama","Georgia","Florida","Tennessee","Kentucky","West Virginia","Virginia","North Carolina","South Carolina", "Maryland","Delaware"),
     Northeast = c("Maine","New Hampshire","Vermont","Massachusetts","Connecticut","Rhode Island","New York","New Jersey","Pennsylvannia"),
     Midwest = c("Ohio","Michigan","Illinois","Indiana","Wisconsin","Minnesota","Iowa","Missouri","North Dakota","South Dakota","Nebraska","Kansas"),
     West = c("Alaska","Hawaii","Washington","Oregon","California","Nevada","Idaho","Utah","Arizona","New Mexico","Colorado","Wyoming","Montana")
   )
   regionconvert4 <- function(x, lookup) {
     out <- x[NA]
     for (nm in names(lookup)) {
       ind <- x %in% lookup[[nm]]
       out[ind] <- nm
     }
     return(out)
   }
   ```

   The intent of this second one is to replace the value (vector of possible values) with the name of the entries in the list.
3. A slight reversal to the previous technique is to provide a lookup of sorts. I'll modify the `regionlist` above and instead of the names being regions, the names are the states. (This could easily be created via other means.)

   ```
   statelist <- setNames(names(tibble::deframe(regiondf)),
                         tibble::deframe(regiondf))
   statelist[1:5]
   #       Texas    Oklahoma    Arkansas   Louisiana Mississippi 
   #     "South"     "South"     "South"     "South"     "South" 
   statelist[ c("Colorado","New Jersey") ]
   #    Colorado  New Jersey 
   #      "West" "Northeast"
   ```

   This removes the need for a function, ala `statelist[AREA]`.
4. A merge/join. This is a little more advanced, but I think is a bit more maintainable in the long-term (e.g., you can maintain the list of states/regions in a simple CSV or spreadsheet which might make it much easier to edit/change/extend, etc). I'll make this new frame from the `regionlist` object, but it can easily be created directly or via more familiar means:

   ```
   regiondf <- tibble::enframe(regionlist, name="region", value="AREA") %>% tidyr::unnest()
   regiondf
   # # A tibble: 50 x 2
   #    region AREA       
   #    <chr>  <chr>      
   #  1 South  Texas      
   #  2 South  Oklahoma   
   #  3 South  Arkansas   
   #  4 South  Louisiana  
   #  5 South  Mississippi
   #  6 South  Alabama    
   #  7 South  Georgia    
   #  8 South  Florida    
   #  9 South  Tennessee  
   # 10 South  Kentucky   
   # # ... with 40 more rows
   ```

Now I'll demonstrate all of those functions with a simple sample data. (Side note: if things don't work for you, it's likely because we don't have your sample data and/or any nuances that only you know. In the future, please provide some sample data for testing and your expected output.)

```
sampledata <- data_frame(AREA = c("Colorado", "California", "New Jersey", "Florida", "Guam"))

sampledata %>%
  mutate(
    r2 = regionconvert2(AREA),
    r3 = regionconvert3(AREA),
    r4 = regionconvert4(AREA, regionlist),
    r5 = statelist[AREA]
  ) %>%
  left_join(regiondf, by = "AREA")
# # A tibble: 5 x 6
#   AREA       r2        r3        r4        r5        region   
#   <chr>      <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>    
# 1 Colorado   West      West      West      West      West     
# 2 California West      West      West      West      West     
# 3 New Jersey Northeast Northeast Northeast Northeast Northeast
# 4 Florida    South     South     South     South     South    
# 5 Guam       <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>
```

(If you want to use the fourth "merge/join" technique, none of the `mutate` is necessary.)

Answer (score 0):

`state.region` is a factor vector, not a function. It has 50 elements, organized by the alphabetical values of state name. To join the data with the data set from the original post, one can convert it along with `state.name` into a tibble as follows.

```
library(tidyverse)
stateNames <- tibble(state = as.character(state.name),region = as.character(state.region))
head(stateNames)
```

...and the first few rows of output:

```
> head(stateNames)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  state      region
  <chr>      <chr> 
1 Alabama    South 
2 Alaska     West  
3 Arizona    West  
4 Arkansas   South 
5 California West  
6 Colorado   West  
>
```

Now the state information can be merged with the `AREA` variable as described in r2evans' answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help, everyone!  I'm new to coding and this website.  I see that someone down-voted this questions.  Can anyone tell me what I did wrong?  Was it because a similar question was already answered?  Just want to know so I can avoid this in the future.

Comment: Your question may have been voted down because you did not follow the guidelines in [How to ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), specifically [How to Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Also, if one of the answers helped you solve the problem, please accept and upvote it. I upvoted @r2evans answer because it was thorough, well written, and illustrated with example code.